# How to analysis sonar data(.raw)? model:EK80

Tags: python-3.x

#I want to read some raw sonar data to csv,follow github guide I just read Ek60 model

```
import echopype.visualize as epviz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import echopype as ep
import _echopype_version
from echopype import open_raw

raw_url ="D:\pycharm\sonar-2\D20230203-T074431.raw"
ed = ep.open_raw(raw_file=raw_url,sonar_model="EK60")
epviz.create_echogram(ed,get_range=True,robust=True)
plt.show()
```